Cannot Connect to SQL Server Database with SqlAlchemy
I am trying to connect to a SQL Server Database with SqlAlchemy but I get an error message whether I use Windows Authentication or SQL server authentication.
Here is what I have tried:
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

serverName = "server"
driverName = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"
databaseName = "POC"
uid= r'domain\username'
pwd= r'password'

conn_string = f"mssql://@{serverName}/{databaseName}?trusted_connection=yes&driver={driverName}"
engine = create_engine(conn_string)

try:
    conn = engine.connect()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

AND
conn_string = f"mssql://{uid}:{pwd}@{serverName}/{databaseName}?driver={driverName}"

I understand why windows authentication does not work because I am running the script from an account that does not have access to the Server. But what is throwing me off is when I give credentials to my account that does have access, I still get the following error:
(pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'domain\\username'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'domain\\username'. (18456)")

I triple checked all the parameters I pass to the connection string and they are all correct.
Everything I found on SO relating to this has not helped me. Any ideas on how I could proceed?

You can't use windows auth that way i think, one just sends that you want to use Windows auth and the login token is taken from the process running and logging in, it's not possible to write in other credentials. You'll have to use impersonation or run the script as the correct account from beginning.

When you specify a username and password you're telling the driver to use SQL Logon authentication, which is not Windows authentication, and you cannot use Windows usernames and passwords to authenticate that way. If you check the SQL Server's error logs for 18456 Login failure messages and compare their State number(s) against those listed at MSSQLSERVER_18456 you'll see exactly why it's failing. I'd expect to see State 6 in this scenario.

@siggemannen I feared that was the case...I need a way to be able to connect to the DB without running from the correct account since this script will be packaged as an exe and distributed to multiple machines. I will have to look into a workaround

This question is similar to: Error 18456. State 6 "Attempting to use an NT account name with SQL Server Authentication.". If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

That's the wrong way to do things, the idea with windows auth is that user running things should be in control. If you embed some other windows auth settings, then you're going against the grain. Funnily though, i think java drivers do support sending specific domain login info, but odbc drivers has been lagging behind the jdbc ones for a while now :)

@siggemannen correct.. mssql jdbc driver supports native authentication (integrated windows security via platfrom specific .dll), Kerberos (set creds via kinit.exe), NTLM (windows creds in connection string), and sql auth (sql user/pass in connection string)
